# AbsolutePath with QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
     if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Guidance.aspx")
        {
            if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
              Reponse.Redirect("http://www.example.com/Guidance.aspx");
            }
            return;
        }
```

The thing is that Guidance can have a querystring with it. I like to then Redirect to the same  page name and append the querystring. Haven't found a way to do this.

```
     if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Guidance.aspx?id='vid09'")
        {
            if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
              Reponse.Redirect("http://www.example.com/Guidance.aspx?id='vid09'");
            }
            return;
        }
```

How can I simplify the code above to do it with any querystring that comes its way.

Comment: See if the string contains 'Guidance.aspx' `preg_match('/(Guidance.aspx)/')` and then put everything after the `?` into a variable and append it to the end when reidirecting

Comment: Use the original url to extract the query string and just append the same query string to the RedirectUrl, there is no easy way of working with query strings in c# that I remember of..

Comment: Maybe you can use IIS URL Rewrite? http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string myUrl = Request.RawUrl.toString();
if (myUrl.Contains("/Guidance.aspx")
    {
        if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
          var queryString = myUrl.Substring(myUrl.IndexOf("?"));
          Reponse.Redirect("http://www.example.com/Guidance.aspx" + queryString);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the AbsoluatePath will give you the querystring (Request.Url.AbsolutePath)

Comment: @NatePet Actually it does, I just tested it on LINQPad

Comment: What about `Request.QueryString`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.UriBuilder.aspx) and replace parts you need. Something like:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
builder.Scheme = "http";
Reponse.Redirect(builder.ToString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get fancy, the URI is already parsed for you (don't do it yourself with unreliable regular expressions). The Url property you're using is a [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) object. You may simply compare the scheme, host, and any HTTP segment you may need, then construct your redirection URI by adding only the query string component from the original URI. All you need is in the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class.